# asp.net center align checkbox

Tags: asp.net, html

Attempting to center align a checkbox, which is displayed using a repeater for each record.

```
asp:Repeater id="rptSelected" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
  <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
    <tr>
      <th style="width:200px;">Contacted</th>
    </tr>
 </HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:200px;">
      <input type="checkbox" class="AlignCheckBox" name='<%# CallUtilityChangeId((int)Eval("CompanyId")) %>'
       <%# SetCheckboxValue((bool)Eval("Contacted"))%> />
    </th>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Using:

```
    .AlignCheckBox
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

but to no avail...any ideas?

thank ye

Comment: Apply the class on the `th`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css you have there will center align the text *within* the textbox. In order to align the textbox **itself**, you need to use that same css but on the texbox's *container*.

A quick example would be:

```
th {
    text-align: center;
}
```

As for your exact code, you could get away with this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:200px; text-align: center;">
      <input type="checkbox" class="AlignCheckBox" name='<%# CallUtilityChangeId((int)Eval("CompanyId")) %>'
       <%# SetCheckboxValue((bool)Eval("Contacted"))%> />
    </th>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Adding it to the style tag of your `th`.

Answer (score 1):

In the ItemTemplate, I think you want "td" tag instead of "th" ;) and add "text-align: center;" to the style attribute:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:200px; text-align: center;">
      <input type="checkbox" name='<%# CallUtilityChangeId((int)Eval("CompanyId")) %>'
      <%# SetCheckboxValue((bool)Eval("Contacted"))%> />
    </td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

apply center align on th of checkbox